# Does a field of characteristic 0 have a primitive $n$-th root of $1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$.
Is it correct to recognize that for any natural number $n$, there is a primitive $n$-th root of $1 \in K$?
Consider $K$ as an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.
In this situation, I thought I should consider in $K\cap\mathbb{C}$.

Is there anything inadequate in this idea?

Comment: what if $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $n=3$?

Comment: in general, the smallest field of characteristic $0$ containing all roots of unity is the maximal abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: What do you mean by $K\cap\mathbb C$, e.g. when $K$ is a [$p$-adic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number)?

Comment: I feel like I understand.

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of $1\in K$.  I have to specify an extension of $K$ to which $\zeta$ belongs because $\zeta$ is a root of $X^n-1 \in K[X]$. The proposition does not hold because I cannot generally specify a field that contains $\mathbb{C}$ and $K$.